# how to add custom fields in registration page of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I want to add `firstname` and `lastname` fields in the registration page of my WordPress site. Can anyone help me on how to add these fields into registration form.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pie-register/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Comment: I need to add custom fields for my site's registration page not for wordpress registration/login page.

Comment: where is your code?? does your site have custom registration page?? if so what language and database it uses?

Comment: yes it has separate registration page. Its in php language. Actually the site is built using a "job monster" theme which is purchased from themeforest.

Comment: @ can you post your code?